# CreateUserAndAccount method gives error "The username is already in use"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using "SimpleMembership".

If I sign up for a Facebook account using the email-id 'xyz@gmail.com' and then sign up internally using the "WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount method" with the same email-id 'xyz@gmail.com' it gives the error:

> The username is already in use

Is it possible to create an account after the creation of an external account, such as Facebook ?